# How to take value from input type number ? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

Hi I whana take value with javascript from input type number field. I whana take value always then new number is select, bescause in other field I whana calculate how much it gone cost.

```
<td>
    <input type="number" id="kiek1000classico" name="kiek1000classico" min="1" max="99">
</td>
<td>
    <script>
        var kiek = document.getElementById("kiek1000classico").value;
    </script>
</td>
```

Now it always return empty string, I just need know how take number every time then it changed without refresh page. I am using wordpress

Comment: no document ready function?

Comment: @Cracker0dks it's pure javascript! and it doesn't require `.ready()`

Comment: You don't have value in your input. Do you ?

Comment: Works just fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AVv6R/), just set `value` attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

you have to wire the `onchange` event of the text box.

For Pure Javascript

```
<input type="number" onchange="checkTextbox(this)" id="kiek1000classico" name="kiek1000classico" min="1" max="99">

<script>
function checkTextbox(element){
    var kiek = element.value;
    alert(kiek);
}
</script>
```

With Jquery it will be more simple

```
<script>

$(function(){
        $('#kiek1000classico').on('change',function(){
              alert($(this).val());
        });
    })

</script>
```

Comment: And how write down variable in JavaScript like echo in php?

Comment: you want to display the value in the webpage?

Comment: I displayed it by document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = kiek;

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#kiek1000classico').change(function () {
              var data = $('#kiek1000classico').val();
              alert(data);
          });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use jquery in wordpress

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#kiek1000classico').change(function(){
  var kiek = parseInt($(this).val());
  alert(kiek);
 });
});
```

This is was for "change" event, you can also use "blur" event in the same manner.